# Block occupies white space when on a new line

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```css
.h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.scada {
  font-family: Scada, sans-serif;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1 scada left">Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 100 (80MJ003YUA)</h1>
<div class="code left">code: U0140224</div>
```

On big resolution it works just fine.
[image]

But when the resolution gets smaller, and the text in this h1 tag (by the way I tried swapping it with a div tag, no difference) goes on a new line, the tag still occupies space on it's right.
[image]

It's not margin/padding/border for sure. I've also tried changing the max-width. Nothing helped so far. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I didn't ask the question properly. I need to be just like it is, on a new line, but not to occupy the whitespace on it's right.

Comment: do U want them to be one under the other ? If U do just give a min-width

Comment: I want it to go to the new line, just like it does now, I just need the tag to become narrower, so that whitespace won't be a part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the browser tries not to creak the word in the middle, so your `div` is actually bigger then the text, however the line is broken early not to break the word.
add:

```
  word-break: break-all;
```

To your div to see the difference.Here is an example:[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhnc6ot9/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 79%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.scada {
  font-family: Scada, sans-serif;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1 scada left">Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 100 (80MJ003YUA)</h1>
<div class="code left">code: U0140224</div>
```

Comment: I've update the question. My apologies for being unclear, it's not quite the same thing I'm looking for.

Comment: use word-break: break-all; it may avoid white space... or try media class in css

Comment: Looks like using word-break is exactly what I need. Thanks.